# Why are dates convert to different format when parsed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, spreadsheet, xls

I am using the [xlsx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx) to parse `.xls` files.

I am having an issue with the date format being different after parsing the file and would like to know why, and perhaps how to fix it?

[Here](https://filebin.net/jm37356p8nkzgycm) is an example file that I have been working with, it is only 3 lines long.

[here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-e9zsto) the code I have so far

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import XLSX from "xlsx";

import './style.css';

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      name: 'React'
    };
  }

   xslToJson = workbook => {
  var data = [];
var sheet_name_list = workbook.SheetNames;
 return XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(workbook.Sheets[sheet_name_list[0]], {raw: false});

};

     handleFile = (file /*:File*/) => {
    /* Boilerplate to set up FileReader */
    const reader = new FileReader();
    const rABS = !!reader.readAsBinaryString;
    reader.onload = e => {
      /* Parse data */
      const bstr = e.target.result;
      const wb = XLSX.read(bstr, { type: rABS ? "binary" : "array" });
      /* Get first worksheet */
      let arr = this.xslToJson(wb);
      console.log(arr)
    };
    if (rABS) reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
    else reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
  };

   handleChange = (e) => {
        const files = e.target.files;
        if (files && files[0]) {
            this.handleFile(files[0]);

        }
    };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input
        type="file"
        onChange={this.handleChange}
        className="inputfile"
        id="embedpollfileinput"
      />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

[image]

**in my xsl file, `DD/MM/YYYY`  format is present.but when i parse xls file it shows me in `MM/DD/YY`**
[image]

```
xslToJson = workbook => {
  var data = [];
var sheet_name_list = workbook.SheetNames;
 return XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(workbook.Sheets[sheet_name_list[0]], {raw: false});

};

     handleFile = (file /*:File*/) => {
    /* Boilerplate to set up FileReader */
    const reader = new FileReader();
    const rABS = !!reader.readAsBinaryString;
    reader.onload = e => {
      /* Parse data */
      const bstr = e.target.result;
      const wb = XLSX.read(bstr, { type: rABS ? "binary" : "array" });
      /* Get first worksheet */
      let arr = this.xslToJson(wb);
      console.log(arr)
    };
    if (rABS) reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
    else reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
  };
```

Comment: I would assume because there is one date representation that Excel expects and then formats it according to settings. What you see in the UI is the formatted variant.

Comment: While I can't really explain the why this is happening (I know nothing about the internals of the `xlsx` package) what I can do is recommend you use [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) to re-format the date if possible.

Comment: A Date instance has no intrinsic "format" *while it's a Date instance*.  The process of making a string into a Date involves an interpretation of the source format, and similarly rendering a Date instance for display involves picking some format by some method.

Comment: @user1538301 i am using `moment` ,but using `moment` it . gives `jan` date instead of `sep`

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx#json suggests setting `dateNF` to *"Use specified date format in string output"*

Comment: Look at https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx/issues/1565

Comment: Bit of an XYProblem, but with moment you can specify the format - if it's giving you Jan as in 9/Jan/19 but you want Sep/1/19 then add that to moment, eg: https://momentjs.com/guides/#/lib-concepts/js-date/ `moment(att_date, 'MM/DD/YYYY', true).format("DD/MM/YYYY")` (or whatever input/output you have, hard to tell with 1 and 9)